# VBA can't get if, elseif, else statement to work

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use a form field to check a table column value to prequalify a query to run this is the code that I have but I am getting a run time error.

```
' Set Warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
If Forms!FrmCopyRoutingMenu!TextTarget = tblQuoteSection1Lines!tblQuoteMstrID Then
    MsgBox ("Quote Section 1 Already Started! Please Copy Individual Sections.")

ElseIf Forms!FrmCopyRoutingMenu!TextTarget = Table!tblQuoteSection2Lines!tblQuoteMstrID Then
    MsgBox ("Quote Section 2 Already Started! Please Copy Individual Sections.")

ElseIf Forms!FrmCopyRoutingMenu!TextTarget = Table!tblQuoteSection3Lines!tblQuoteMstrID Then
    MsgBox ("Quote Section 3 Already Started! Please Copy Individual Sections.")

ElseIf Forms!FrmCopyRoutingMenu!TextTarget = Table!tblQuoteSection4Lines!tblQuoteMstrID Then
    MsgBox ("Quote Section 4 Already Started! Please Copy Individual Sections.")

ElseIf Forms!FrmCopyRoutingMenu!TextTarget = Table!tblQuoteSection5Lines!tblQuoteMstrID Then
    MsgBox ("Quote Section 5 Already Started! Please Copy Individual Sections.")

Else
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be wise to post the error message(s) you are encountering with your issue. This will enable users to determine what is going on.

Comment: Run-time error '424' Object Required

Comment: I don't think you can link to a table like that.  You are going to have to open the table with a recordset object and grab the column that way.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should most certainly not have 5 tables `tblQuoteSection1..5Lines`, but one table `tblQuoteSectionLines` with a section column. This will make everything easier.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to check if the value in TextTarget is anywhere in the ID field of each table? Does this work?

```
Dim target As String
Dim Found As Boolean

target = Forms!FrmCopyRoutingMenu!TextTarget
Found = False

For i = 1 To 5
If DCount("tblQuoteMstrID", "tblQuoteSection" & i & "Lines", "tblQuoteMstrID = '" & target & "'") > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Quote Section " & i & " Already Started! Please Copy Individual Sections.")
    Found = True
End If
Next i

If Not Found Then
    'code to run query goes here
End If
```

Comment: This looks like it might work but I can't get it to carry over to my else statement that runs the Query if it is not true.

Comment: @Corey One way would be to include a Boolean that can be checked after the loop has finished. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your help on this but I got it to work by using a query to create a single table of the desired Master ID's from each table and then I used if (DAVG()>0). Again thank you for the help on this your ideas were exactly what I needed to start looking at the issue from another direction.

Comment: In terms of technique, using a temp table to identify the IDs you're looking for certainly works, but it can easily become a Rube Goldberg machine if you're not careful.  Looping through your datasets like @Leroy recommended would be the preferred way to go on this.